# Task was destroyed but it is pending! in my spark app

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, python-asyncio, goblin

i have wrote goblin ogm sample into my spark app, but i got Task was destroyed but it is pending!
below is my code
def savePartition(p):
    from goblin import element, properties

```
class Brand(element.Vertex):
    name = properties.Property(properties.String)

import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

from goblin.app import Goblin
app = loop.run_until_complete(Goblin.open(loop))
app.register(Brand)

async def go(app):
    session = await app.session()

    for i in p:
        if i['brand']:
            traversal = session.traversal(Brand)
            result = await traversal.has(Brand.name, i['brand']).oneOrNone()

            if not result:
                brand = Brand()
                brand.name = i['brand']
                session.add(brand)

    await session.flush()

loop.run_until_complete(go(app))
```

rdd = rdd.foreachPartition(savePartition)
i am wonder how to close the response in above code. thanks very much.